# Comment History in Sales Order

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am using paypal in payment method but it seems that the IPN transaction ID is displaying to admin panel Comment History, is there a way to customize the Comment History to blank instead of notification of transaction ID from paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below function in this model class **Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment** line no 1379 and override this model in local pool.

```
 protected function _appendTransactionToMessage($transaction, $message)
{
    if ($transaction) {
        $txnId = is_object($transaction) ? $transaction->getHtmlTxnId() : $transaction;
        $message .= ' ' . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Transaction ID: "%s".', $txnId);
    }
    return $message;
}
```

And replace your message with this function $message variable.